# unix shell, redirect output but keep on stdin

Tags: unix, shell, io-redirection

I'd like to have a shell script redirect stdout of a child process in the following manner

1. Redirect stdout to a file
2. Display the output of the process in real time

I know I could do something like

```
#!/bin/sh

./child > file
cat file
```

But that would not display stdout in real time. For instance, if the child was

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 1
sleep 1
echo 2
```

The user would see "1" and "2" printed at the same time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
./child | tee file
```

`tee` will copy its standard input to any file on the command line and to standard output as well.

Comment: Another tip: 'tee -a' is for appending to files if you want that, equivalent to using >> instead of > with normal shell redirection.

Answer (score -1):

I use: sponge, from moreutils
http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge

you can do something like that:

$ grep something largefile | sponge largefile

Comment: How does it fullfill "Display the output of the process in real time"?